# How to overload functions / refer to functions with same name in separate scripts in R?

Tags: r, shiny

I have functions that basically use the same parameters to build different models,  and
output results in the same format. So to organize them, I separated them into different scripts.
I want to name the functions the same, and refer to them by the name of the script, as how it would be done in object oriented languages like this.

```
class ModelA {
    static void lambda(String sarg) {}
    static void lambda(int iarg) {}
}

class ModelB{
    static void lambda(..) {}
}

class Program{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ModelA.lambda("somestring");
        ModelA.lambda(1);
        ModelB.lambda(..);
    }
}
```

In R, if two functions are named the same, one will override the other. So I manually prefixed them to prevent Model B's lambda from overriding the lambda in A.
Is there a way to use namespaces/environments to achieve what I want?

```
#server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
    ...
    callModule(module=a.server, id="ModelA")
    callModule(module=b.server, id= "ModelB")
    ...
})


#ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage( 
...
tabsetPanel(
    a.ui.tab(id="ModelA")
    b.ui.tab(id="ModelB")
)
...
))

#global.R
source("modelA.R")
source("modelB.R")

display <- function(input, output, session, lambda){
    ...
    lambda(output, session)
    ...
}

#modelA.R
a.ui.tab <- function(id){
    ns <-NS(id)
    tabPanel(title="Model A",
        output(ns("results")) 
    )
}

a.server<- function(input, output, session){
    output$results <- renderUI({
        display(output, session, a.lambda)
    })
}

a.lambda <- function(output, session){
    ...create a model using the same parameters
}


#modelB.R
b.ui.tab <- function(id){
    ns <-NS(id)
    tabPanel(title="Model B",
        output(ns("results")) 
    )
}
b.server<- function(input, output, session){
    output$results <- renderUI({
        display(output, session, b.lambda)
    })
}

b.lambda <- function(output, session){
    ...create a different model using the same parameters
}
```

Comment: You could source your R files into seperate environments using the `local` parameter of `source` and then evaluate the function call in those environments.

Comment: S3 classes may help http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html

Comment: Reference classes may be a better approach than S3 for this.